# How do I call a button method from ViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a method addClicked that gets called when a button on the navigation bar is clicked.  I want to call this later on in the code without having to click the button.  What is the syntax for calling this method?

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                             initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
                                             target:self action:@selector(add_Clicked:)];
```

The function is calls looks like this:

```
- (void) add_Clicked:(id)sender {
```

I tried:

```
[self add_Clicked:];

[add_Clicked:];

[self add_Clicked: self];
```

The last works but I'm not sure why.  Can someone provide a link to the doc the would explain how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass something for the sender. That's why the last one works.

Try [self add_Clicked:nil]

Comment: Thank you for explaining that.  I now have another question as I am trying to access a variable set in this first RootViewController class from a later AddQuoteViewController class and can't seem to access the variable.  I posted the question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104327/how-do-i-pass-object-from-one-viewcontroller-to-another-viewcontroller), if you could take a look at what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The last one works because you added the current class as the target  "target:self", but the target is (id) so the sender could be any object in theory.

Comment: The fact that your NOT using sender in the add_Clicked: method, is what makes the solutions ok.  If you do use the sender in the call, then passing null or self will probably crash.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to the suggestions, depending on what your doing, is to add another method to the class and have the method called form the callback to call it.

```
- (void) add_Clicked:(id)sender {
  [self goAddSomething];
}


- (void) goAddSomething {
  /* add the code here to handle add. */
}
```

Then in another part of your code, you could call [self goAddSomething]; and not have to use nil.